# Tiling patterns

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, tiling

I'm looking for efficient solution/algorithm for tiling : the layout of the decking tiles.

We want to build system that will calculate the mutual placement of columns and beams (beams, joist) with support of irregular shape.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: greedy algorithms will bring some solutions, but as it is NP-hard problem i suggest using evolutions algorithms

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but maybe someone can use the answer....

This problem is similar to the integrated circuit layout problem when designing computer chips. As you can imagine, this is a rich source of methods. Try looking at:

- [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing

You can also view this as a global optimization problem. For an overview look at:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_optimization#Approaches

Comment: without actual example of use are these links useless. the knowledge of these methods alone does not lead to solution.